# AngularJS how to update a JSON value with a dynamic key and an $http response?

Tags: angularjs, json

I have this JSON example:

```
  $scope.channels = {
    "ch1": {
      id: "ch1",
      data: {}
    },
    "ch2": {
      id: "ch2",
      data: {}
    }
  };
```

## QUE 1

How do I update the `data: {}` part with the dynamic key ?
something like:

```
  for ( var c in $scope.channels ) {
    $http.get(JSON_PATH + c + '.json').then(function(res){
      // DOES NOT WORK
      $scope.channels[c]["data"] = res.data;

      // ALSO DOES NOT WORK
      var section = $scope.channels[c];
          section.data = res.data;
      $scope.channels[c] = section;
    });
  }
```

The result of `$scope.channels` is now to have a *new* section called "data" instead of being under the key == "ch1" (i.e).

In addition, Sublime Text 3 also gives a warning which I'm not sure why? ( it's not like I'm using `this` or something:
`181 don't make functions within a loop`

## QUE 2

I solved the above problem by actually create an external function and call it within the loop.

So I was wondering why the above code in Que1 doesn't work, while this does:

```
function load_data(id) {
 $http.get(JSON_PATH + c + '.json').then(function(res){
   var section = $scope.channels[c];
   var section.data = res.data;

   $scope.channels[c] = section;   // WORK
   });
}

for ( var c in $scope.channels ) {
  load_data(c);
}
```

Comment: Sublime gives that warning because you should declare your function elsewhere outside the loop, then inside the loop, call the function with passed in parameters (like the loop index), as you demonstrate in Que 2.

Comment: have you tried using console.log or the debugger to step through and see the value of each variable at every step and compare them?

Comment: yes, I have the data I need in the console.log ... but Angular's $scope receive it different, because I'm not sure how to update the JSON, it does not work as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Que 1 the for loop has continued it's cycle while the $http method is asyncronously processing. The "c" variable has lost it's original context and value. I believe it is destroyed once the for loop completes.

In Que 2, "c" is now "id", and has been passed in as a static value that will continue to be available to anything inside the function closure regardless of asyncronous activity. The function makes a reference to "c" and ceases to care whether the loop destroys it or not.

This has to do with function closures, and will need someone with a better understanding to explain it in detail.

You should change "c" to "id" in Que 2 though, inside your function.

Also, as a semi-related side note, if you are going to loop a series of $http calls, you might want to look up the $q.all documentation and read about how to build promise arrays where you can detect resolution of all calls rather than just individual calls. It can be quite useful.

Comment: regarding #1 - make sense, regarding #2 - yes its a copy-paste mistake here, thanks for the tip - I will look into it !